# Salesforce license constraints

Tags: licenses, developer-edition

I need to create more user under salesforce license. But as I am using an developer account, so I am restricted to only two.
Is there any alternative to that?

Answer (score 1):

Freeze a User account, and deactivate it. then you can create new user for same license. But there cannot be more than limited users active at a time.

So create a user, do something in his context. Deactivate it. 
Create another user. do something in his context...

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative to it. You can create more users from other available licenses such as standard user etc.

This is imposed by salesforce itself.

Comment: I am working on "Recruiting app" being provided by salesforce for practice purpose. So how am I suppose to go ahead?